# How to use local database .sdf in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I am trying to make a database application. I added local database from

```
add > new item > local database.sdf
```

In Server Explorer, I created a table in the database. But I am having trouble connecting to it.

I want to show all the data in a DataGrid.

My code:

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=""c:\users\asus\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WpfApplicationLocalDB\WpfApplicationLocalDB\LocalDB.sdf""";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Student", conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

conn.Close();

List<DataRow> lis = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
DataGridView.ItemsSource = lis;
```

But when I build it, Visual Studio finds `conn.open();` error. A message says that

> SqlException was unhandled by user

Please help...

Also, can anyone suggest a tutorial of how can I create a simple database application in C#? Please help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687144

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a `.sdf` file, you're using Microsoft SQL Server **Compact Edition** (SQL Server CE).

When using SQL Server CE, you must use `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` classes - not `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` (those are for the "full", server-based versions of SQL Server)