# Dynamically create search parameters wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, modern-ui

Suppose I have following requirement:
I want to be able to create a list of rules that will look like this:

```
         Keyword          ToBeDeleted    ToBeMoved
Rule1:   "test keyword"   true           false
Rule2:   "test keyword2"  false          true
```

According to this rules I want to find all documents from specific path and to needed action according to my rules.

**My Question:**
What is the best way to store this rules dynamically in an WPF application,I need to be able to add/update/delete rules when needed using UI .

**In my mind are following scenarios:**

1. Store them in a XML File.
2. Store them in a database(Access probably)

Does anybody know better solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is to steer clear from Access!

XML is a good option unless you don't want it modified or seen by users, which would mean you could encrypt it. If you go the XML route, I highly recommend looking into serialization.

I would personally look into [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or SQL Server Compact. There are many comparisons of the two you can Google for their pro's and con's. Here is a great blog post on the differences of them and others: [Link](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you the [SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) to create a local database.

For how to use the local database in your program please read through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720110/how-to-use-local-database-sdf-in-c-sharp-wpf).